# Can disguise self hide an Aarakocra's wings?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, races

Can *disguise self* hide an Aarakocra's natural wings because they are hiding as a "different race"? Would this allow a creature to create wings to become an Aarakocra? If a creature has wings and hides them, would they be revealed if used in flight? If a creature manifests wings while under *disguise self*'s effects, would they need to recast it to hide them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### It can make the wings look like a different limb, but your Aarakocra is stuck with 6 limbs.

*Disguise self* says:

> You can't change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs.

The phrase "same basic arrangement of limbs" indicates that an Aarakocra with 6 limbs using *disguise self* must have 6 limbs.

#### You can probably work around this with some creativity and generosity from the DM.

*Disguise self* also states:

> You make yourself--including your *clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person*--look different

This leads me to believe we should be able to conceal the extra limbs with some sort of pack on our back. As a kid I read a book about a young girl with dragon wings who always wore a back pack to hide them. *Disguise self* should be able to produce a similar effect, but your mileage may vary depending on your DM.

Comment: AFAIK it only exists in 5e homebrew at the moment, but [Thri-Keen](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Thri-kreen) would be a six-limbed option. Whether a giant bug-humanoid is less distinctive than an Aaracocra is another matter...

Comment: @Punintended I imagine the prevalence of entomophobia far exceeds that of ornithophobia.

Comment: Ugh, way to trigger my sesquipedalophobia

Comment: Searching google suggests the book might be *Raising Dragons*, by Bryan Davis ( [Goodreads link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/352270.Raising_Dragons) ), in case it interests you.

Comment: @BardicWizard That is the one.

Comment: Could you disguise self as a centaur?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I'd rule no, as that seems to be a substantially different arrangement of limbs, despite it being six limbs.